# Setting ListColumn .Range.ColumnWidth

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to equalize the width of two columns on a spreadsheet using a sub that receives a Worksheet Name and two ListColumn index values. One column contains a value and the other is empty. I want to make the empty column the same width as the first one.

Here is the relevant code I have:

```
Set colSrc = tbl.ListColumns(colSrcIndex)
Set colDest = tbl.ListColumns(colDestIndex)
        
colWidth = colSrc.Range.ColumnWidth
      
colDest.Range.ColumnWidth = colWidth
```

When I try to run this, it throws a Runtime 1004 Error stating `Unable to set the ColumnWidth property of the Range class`. Every reference I have looked at says this is correct.

I have tried using the "A:A" version of it, using .EntireColumn, going from the ListColumn to the ListObject to the Worksheet itself. All if it throws the same error.

Comment: What value is `colWidth` when it fails?  Are any of your sheets protected?

Comment: `colSrc.Range.ColumnWidth` = `5.71` and `colDest.Range.ColumnWidth` is `10.29`

None of the sheets are protected. The sheet this is being applied to is actually created on the fly further up in the sub. If it is relevant, I am AutoFitting them right before I try to equalize columns 7/8 and 9/10

Comment: I can only get that error if the sheet's protected, otherwise it works fine for me.

Comment: I just double checked by `Debug.print ws.ProtectedContents` and it returns `False` so I don't see how the sheet could be protected.

Comment: I also just ran `Sheet().Unprotect`, got no prompt about a password, etc. and it still threw the error.

Comment: There’s something which is causing your sheet to behave differently from mine but protection was my only guess…

Comment: Can you show the whole code/sub?

Comment: I can produce the same error when `colWidth` is of the wrong type e.g. `Dim colWidth As String` (wrong!). It should be `Dim colWidth As Double`. But you don't need the variable: `colDest.Range.ColumnWidth = colSrc.Range.ColumnWidth`.

Answer (score 0):

`ColumnWidth` property is equal to the width of one character in the Normal style.
So if you use different typed characters the width will not be the same, and in some cases with different values you can get errors.
So, use the `Width` property for all the columns in question, this property is in points.